# Android checkbox saving and showing via SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, android-checkbox

I have this Activity and I have 2 checkboxes, when the user clicks one of them it will be checked and saved  but if I close the app and reopen it the checkboxes are not saved, which could be the problem? It's not saving, or it's not loading?

Here is my code:

```
package com.myappisawesome;
 
import com.myappisawesome.R;
import com.pushbots.push.Pushbots;

import android.R.string;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.Toast;
 
public class settup extends Activity {
     private String SENDER_ID = "ccccc";
     private String PUSHBOT_ID = "ccccc";
     public static final String PREFS_NAME = "BuyMeCheckBoxes";
 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.notifsettings);
        Pushbots.init(this, SENDER_ID , PUSHBOT_ID);
        Pushbots.getInstance().setMsgReceiver(GoToApp.class);
        Pushbots.getInstance().setRegStatus(true);

      
         final CheckBox auto = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
         final CheckBox imobiliare = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
          SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        boolean c1 = settings.getBoolean("auto", false);
        boolean c2 = settings.getBoolean("imobiliare", false);
        
        auto.setChecked(c1);
        imobiliare.setChecked(c2);
        
         
      
         
           if (auto.isChecked()) {
               auto.setChecked(false);
               Pushbots.getInstance().tag(getApplicationContext(), "auto", null);
              
           }
          
           
           
           
           if (imobiliare.isChecked()) {
               imobiliare.setChecked(false);
               Pushbots.getInstance().tag(getApplicationContext(), "imobiliare", null);
     
           }
           
          
           
    }
    
    
   
 
    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
       super.onStop();
       final CheckBox auto = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
       final CheckBox imobiliare = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
  
      // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
      // All objects are from android.context.Context
      SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
      
      boolean checkBoxValue1 = auto.isChecked();
      boolean checkBoxValue2 = imobiliare.isChecked();  
      
      editor.putBoolean("auto", checkBoxValue1);
      editor.putBoolean("imobiliare", checkBoxValue2);
      editor.commit();;
    }
     
        
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    auto.setChecked(settings.getBoolean("auto", false));
    auto.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("auto", auto.isChecked());
                editor.commit();;
            }
        });
```

use setOnCheckedChangeListener in your oncreate. And save your preferences there instead of onstop. It is not a good practice to save your preferences in onstop.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are setting the status of your checkbox and then overwriting it later on in your activity.
You do `auto.setChecked(c1);`

Then later you do `if (auto.isChecked()) {
               auto.setChecked(false);
}`

Answer (score 0):

you must use onCheckboxClicked(View view) listener to get the user input and save it.